# Taking so much time when i insert 10k data in coredata ?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my project concept i need a insert 10k data when user open the application. I integrate core data for storing data but its take 1 to 5 minutes. 
Here is my code ?

```
func inserChatMessage(_ message: String, chatId: String, onCompletion completionHandler:((_ message: ChatMessage) -> Void)?) {
    var objMessage: ChatMessage? = nil
    if let obj = ChatMessage.createEntity() {
        objMessage = obj
    }
    objMessage?.messageId = ""
    objMessage?.message = message
    objMessage?.chatId = chatId
    objMessage?.senderId = AIUser.current.userId
    objMessage?.createAt = Date()
    objMessage?.updateAt = Date()
    let cManager = CoreDataManager.sharedManager
    cManager.saveContext()

    if let completionHandler = completionHandler, let objMessage = objMessage {
        completionHandler(objMessage)
    }
}
```

Comment: That code adds one message. To add 10k records it may take some time, run it in the background and only call saveContext() when finished or periodically. or provide a pre-seeded db with your app so it can launch with this data already

Comment: Defer the `save`. You'll see massive gains since you're moving from 10k transactions to just 1... Still, @Scriptable's suggestion for a pre-seeded db is a better solution.

Comment: @Scriptable Can you please provide a any demo so i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Coredata is not a threadsafe. And as per your requirement you need to save large amount of data on app launch. So If you will save those data using main thread, your app will get hanged. So Instead on saving large amount of data on main thread you can save those data on background thread. Coredata is supporting multi threading concept by providing parent child context concept.

I have done same in one of my project and its working fine. Here i have attached code.

```
 func savePersonalMessagesOnBackGroundThread(arrMessages:NSArray,responseData:@escaping () -> Void)
{
    print(arrMessages)

    let temporaryChatContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    temporaryChatContext.parent = self.managedObjectContext
    temporaryChatContext.perform({() -> Void in
        for i in 0..<arrMessages.count
        {
            let msgDic = arrMessages[i] as! NSDictionary
            _ = self.saveMessageInLocalDB(dictMessage: msgDic, managedObjectContext: temporaryChatContext, onBackground: true)

            if i == arrMessages.count - 1 {
                do {
                    try temporaryChatContext.save()
                    runOnMainThreadWithoutDeadlock {
                        DLog(message: "Thred \(Thread.isMainThread)")
                        if(self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges)
                        {
                            self.saveContext()
                            responseData()
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

 func saveMessageInLocalDB(dictMessage:NSDictionary, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext,onBackground:Bool) -> Chat
{
    var chatObj : Chat! = Chat()
    var receiveId: Int32!
    var flag:Bool = false
    print(dictMessage)

   // let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"uniqueId == %@ and senderId = %d and receiverId = %d","\(dictMessage.value(forKey:keyuniqueId)!)",Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keysenderId) as! Int64),Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keyreceiverId) as! Int64))
     let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"uniqueId == %@","\(dictMessage.value(forKey:keyuniqueId)!)")
    let objContext = managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Chat>(entityName: ENTITY_CHAT)
    let disentity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: ENTITY_CHAT, in: objContext)!
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.entity = disentity

    do{
        let results = try  managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [Chat]
        if(results.count > 0)
        {
            chatObj = results[0]
            chatObj.messageId = Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keymessageId) as! Int64)
            chatObj.dateOnly = dictMessage.value(forKey:keydateOnly) as! String?
        }
        else{

                //receiveId = Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keyreceiverId) as! Int64)
                //self.createNewChatObject(dictMessage: dictMessage, receiverId: receiveId, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
                chatObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:ENTITY_CHAT,into: managedObjectContext) as? Chat

                if dictMessage[keymessageId] != nil {
                    chatObj.messageId = dictMessage.value(forKey:keymessageId) as! Int32
                }

                if(chatObj.message?.length != 0)
                {
                    chatObj.message = dictMessage.value(forKey:keychatMessage) as? String
                }

                chatObj.messageType = Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keymessageType) as! Int64)
                chatObj.senderId = Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keysenderId) as! Int64)
                if(chatObj.senderId != Int32((APP_DELEGATE.loggedInUser?.id!)!))
                {
                    let contactObj = self.getContactByContactId(contactId: Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keysenderId) as! Int64))
                    if(contactObj == nil)
                    {
                       _ = self.saveUnknownUserASContact(msgDict: dictMessage as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
                    }
                }
                chatObj.receiverId = Int32(dictMessage.value(forKey:keyreceiverId) as! Int64)
                chatObj.uniqueId = dictMessage.value(forKey:keyuniqueId) as? String
                chatObj.mediaName = dictMessage.value(forKey:keymediaName) as? String

                print(NSDate())
                if dictMessage[keycreatedDate] != nil {
                    let utcDate : NSDate =  DateFormater.getUTCDateFromUTCString(givenDate: dictMessage.value(forKey:keycreatedDate) as! String)

                    chatObj.createdDate = utcDate
                    chatObj.updatedDate =  utcDate
                }
                else
                {
                    chatObj.createdDate = NSDate()
                    chatObj.updatedDate = NSDate()
                }

                if(chatObj.senderId == Int32((APP_DELEGATE.loggedInUser?.id)!))
                {
                    chatObj.chatUser = chatObj.receiverId
                }
                else
                {
                    chatObj.chatUser = chatObj.senderId
                }

                if dictMessage[keystatus] != nil {
                    chatObj.status =  Bool((dictMessage.value(forKey:keystatus) as! Int64) as NSNumber)
                }

                switch Int(chatObj.messageType)
                {
                case MSG_TYPE.MSG_Text.rawValue:
                    chatObj.cellType = (chatObj.senderId != Int32((APP_DELEGATE.loggedInUser?.id!)!) ? Int32(CELL_TYPE.CELL_TEXT_RECEIVER.rawValue) : Int32(CELL_TYPE.CELL_TEXT_SENDER.rawValue))

                case MSG_TYPE.MSG_Image.rawValue:
                    chatObj.cellType = (chatObj.senderId != Int32((APP_DELEGATE.loggedInUser?.id!)!) ? Int32(CELL_TYPE.CELL_IMAGE_RECEIVER.rawValue) : Int32(CELL_TYPE.CELL_IMAGE_SENDER.rawValue))
                    self.saveMedia(chatObj: chatObj)

                default :
                    // chatObj.cellType = Int32(CELL_TYPE.CELL_LOAD_MORE.rawValue)
                    break
                }
            }


            //   deviceMake = 1;
            if(!onBackground)
            {
                self.saveContext()
            }
        }
    catch
    {

    }

    return chatObj

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the basic example below I can insert 10k records very quickly. The main thing that has changed here compared to your code is that I loop through and create the entities and then call `save()` at the very end. So you are performing one write call to the db instead of 10k. You are writing more information in that one call but it is still much quicker.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var sharedContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let messages = getMessages(), messages.count > 0 {
            printMessages(messages: messages)
        } else {
            loadChatMessages()
            printMessages(messages: getMessages())
        }
    }

    private func printMessages(messages: [Message]?) {

        guard let messages = messages else { return }

        for message in messages {
            print(message.message)
        }
    }

    private func getMessages() -> [Message]? {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
        let messages = try? self.sharedContext?.fetch(request)
        return messages ?? nil
    }

    private func loadChatMessages() {

        var counter = 1
        while counter <= 10000 {

            let message = Message(entity: Message.entity(), insertInto: self.sharedContext)
            message.message = "This is message number \(counter)"
            message.read = false
            message.timestamp = Date()

            counter = counter + 1
        }

        do {
            try self.sharedContext?.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in my comment above, you can improve this further by doing it in the background (see Twinkle's answer for an example of how to switch to a background thread), you can also provide a pre-filled (pre-seeded) core data database that already contains the 10k records with your app. so it doesn't need to load this on initial load.

To do this you would fill the db locally on your dev machine and then copy it to the project bundle. On initial load you can check to see if your db filename exists in the documents folder or not. If it doesn't copy it over from the bundle and then use that DB for core data.